# Built-in Markdown shortcut disappeared

Tags: markdown, visual-studio-code

The built-in `VSCode markdown preview` simply disappeared on my installed copy.

**Has anyone seen something like that before that can show me where I can find a solution?**

By "disappeared" I mean it doesn't show up on context menu nor in the list shown after pressing <kbd>ctrl+shift+p</kbd>.

#### Updated

- 1. The problem started because I decided to get rid of unnecessary    VSCode plugins. Previously I was using `Markdown Preview Enhanced` and decided to use the built-in markdown preview.
- 2. I've already tried to uninstall/reinstall `VSCode` and it made no difference: it's still not showing the markdown preview.

Comment: Which OS do you use? I had the same issue using Ubuntu and did solve the problem as described in my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65309903/11687201

Comment: I was using windows by the time. Actually, I haven't tried your answer because I don't use that computer anymore.

Answer (score 1):

So try reinstall VSCode or install some extension for Markdown, for example, Markdown Preview Enhanced.

Comment: Oh, I've already tried reinstalling it. The point is exactly I'm getting rid of unnecessary plugins and I had just removed Markdown Preview Enhanced. I'll update my question with that info.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer above, reinstalling VSCode will not solve the problem at least for Ubuntu users.

Comment: When reinstalling the "Markdown Preview Enhanced" the button will appear, but for me this was not an option, because I did not want to use this extension anymore because I did not like the way this extension renders the markdown preview.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after uninstalling the extension `Markdown Preview Enhanced` and solved this problem on my system `Ubuntu 20.04` with `VSCode 1.52.0` the following way:

Solution, there might be better ones:

1. I checked the location of the global VSCode user `settings.json` file. It is located at `~/.config/Code/User/settings.json`. Then I deleted the folder `~/.config/Code/`.
2. Then I started VSCode again and the preview button appeared.

Things I tried first, but did not solve the problem:

- Uninstalling and reinstalling `VSCode` did not solve the problem.
- Also deleting the folder `~\.vscode` did not help.

Comment: I have this problem on Ubuntu and it might be related to `Markdown Preview Enhanced`. I followed the instructions, but as soon as I copy my `settings.json` content back, the problem reappears. There isn't anything in my `settings.json` related to markdown though.

Comment: I commented out lines until I found this line, which seems to break it: `"files.associations": {"*.md": "mdx"},`.